# Fabric js how to add text on image

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I need to add text on img object
my code

```
$("#c2").click(function(){
fabric.Image.fromURL('/some/link/free_circle_2.png', function(img){
    img.setWidth(50);
    img.setHeight(50);
    canvas.add(img);

  });
});
```

after adding image i need add number centered of this image.
I know i need to change `canvas.add(img);` to `canvas.sendToBack(img);` but how to add text keeping the position of the image

Comment: put image and text inside a group

Comment: @Infer-on ok, but question was adding text after add image on canvas
(after adding image i need add number centered of this image)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To keep the position of your text, based upon the position of your image, you should use a [Group](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Group.html), like this:

```
var group = new fabric.Group([img, text], {
          left: 150,
          top: 100,

        });
```

Then to place your text in the middle of your image, since the position of your text its relative to the group, you should do something like this:

```
text.set("top", (img.getBoundingRect().height / 2) - (text.width / 2));
text.set("left", (img.getBoundingRect().width / 2) - (text.height / 2));
```

Where [getBoundingRect](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.js.html#line13438) returns coordinates of object's bounding rectangle (left, top, width, height)

then,

Try yourself the following runnable example if it meets your needs:

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

$("#c2").click(function() {
  fabric.Image.fromURL('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/25/Herma_of_Plato_-_0049MC.jpg', function(img) {

    img.setWidth(100);
    img.setHeight(100);

    var text = new fabric.Text("01", {
      fontFamily: 'Comic Sans',
      fontSize: 20
    });

    text.set("top", (img.getBoundingRectHeight() / 2) - (text.width / 2));
    text.set("left", (img.getBoundingRectWidth() / 2) - (text.height / 2));
    var group = new fabric.Group([img, text], {
      left: 100,
      top: 25,

    });

    canvas.add(group);
  });
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px dashed #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.4/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id='c' width=300 height=150 '></canvas>
<br>
<button id='c2'>ok</button>
```